# Como fazer um submit que zera um contador

Tags: javascript, html, html5, arduino

Eu não entendo de javascript e não to sabendo como pesquisar para fazer um botao que quando apertado zerasse meu contador que é uma variável global

```
<form id="btn" method="get">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="zerar"onclick="submit();">
</form>
<script>
    function ssubmit(){
         document.getElementById("btn".submit());
    }
</script>
```

> dai ele chama uma outra função que resetaria a variavel "num"
>   aonde eu coloco para chamar a outra função?

Comment: Qual a variável? Poderia fornecer um exemplo de código um pouco mais detalhado?

Comment: oi, então a variavel é um inteiro normal mesmo - >int num = 3;
e ela fica lá no topo do código.

Comment: eu estou trabalhando com arduino num projeto da faculdade, e são 3  blocos as entradas,  o html, e a função de contador + o reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa mesmo que o botão seja um submit? Porque você pode controlar o clique em qualquer elemento para isso. De qualquer forma, segue.

```html
<form id="btn" method="get">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="zerar" onclick="ssubmit();">
</form>
<script>
    function ssubmit(){
         num = 0; //assumindo que seja num a variável global zerada
         document.getElementById("btn".submit()); //procede o submit normal do formulário (isso vai recarregar a página, daí perde o sentido o código).
    }
</script>
```

Já caso você queira que, em vez de `submit`, aconteça só a chamada da função, você pode fazer:

```html
<button onclick="ssubmit();">Zerar</button>
<script>
    function ssubmit(){
        num = 0; //de novo, assumindo que num seja a variável global
        outraFuncao(); // chama uma outra função para fazer seja lá o que você quiser fazer
    }
</script>
```

Caso eu não tenha respondido sua pergunta, explicite melhor o que você precisa.

Comment: Oi amigo, eu dei um outro jeito, trabalhar com arduino é muito confuso e tenho outros trabalhos pra fazer u.u
fiz uma função que lê a url e quando isso acontecer entra no meu if e zera, tem uns bugs, mas ta funcionando xD
Obrigado mesmo assim